# Blend that adding color instead of just replacing?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there a way to add color's value on pixel (Instead of settings) when drawing?

My pesudo code for example:

```
//DrawPixel( int x, int y, Color color ); - Puts pixel to color buffer with specific place.
DrawPixel( 0, 0, Red );
DrawPixel( 0, 0, Green );
```

And after I execute this code, the `0,0` pixel's color is the result of `Red+Green`. (Yellow)
I don't talk only about drawing pixels or blend. Is there a way in OpenGL to make it done?

Comment: is DrawPixel your own function? or provided by OpenGL

Comment: @Need4Sleep The code I showed in the post is pesado code.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Yeah I was wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. It's called GL_FUNC_ADD. In addition to transparency there are a handful of other useful [blending functions​](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Blend_Equations).

In earlier opengl versions 
Gl.BlendFunc(Gl.SRC_COLOR,Gl.DST_COLOR) might just do the trick.

Comment: I've initialized GLEW and I've OpenGL 2.1 but this function doesn't work. (Throws exception)

Comment: @FijiWiji: Nothing in OpenGL throws exceptions. It's a C API.

Comment: @NicolBolas It says that I am trying to call 0x00000000.

Comment: Sorry but both function doesn't additive color :(.

Comment: I just needed to disable the depth test.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Aki Suihkonen's answer, you may also need to call glEnable(GL_BLEND) to turn blending on.  You said it is currently just replacing the color which sounds like you have blending turned off.

Assuming you have initialized glew properly, when an OpenGL call throws an exception saying you are trying to call 0x00000000 it means that that API is not available in your version of OpenGL, so make sure you are using the correct function for your version of OpenGL.